# Missing Number Picker and many other in palette from android studio 3.3?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-3.0, android-studio-3.3, android-palette

I am using Android Studio 3.3.2. I didn't find the NumberPicker in the palette which was in Expert tab on older versions of Android Studio. What to do?[Screenshot of my palette are given below:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rVsCJ.png)

Comment: Yeah, surprisingly a few widgets were lost when Android Studio updates were made since 3.1. See this: https://www.i-programmer.info/news/193-android/11668-android-studio-31-released-widgets-lost.html

There is no official mention of these missing widgets. And, I've not seen many people complain about it either, that's telling of how not important they were. Mostly, I've stuck with using the XML instead of the UI design tool.

The widget is still supported as far as I can see. Just put needed widgets in XML Layout and see if it is rendering.

Answer (score 1):

Just type in `<NumberPicker` in the XML File and Studio will suggest the NumberPicker.
From there on you can adjust it also in the Design View.

Comment: @reverie_ss Please do not recommend using comments to new users who do not yet have that privilege. That gives a wrong impression.

Comment: Mopreme, all of your post which can be considered an actual answer was hidden by the broken formatting. Please study https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help in order to avoid that problem in future posts. Be careful with saying thanks. You might be mistaken for ONLY saying thanks, which is conisdered inappropriate here. Also please take the [tour] for more helpful information on how StackOverflow works. Thanks for your contribution. Have fun.

Comment: @reverie_ss I discovered that we both were wrong. The author DID actually post an answer, it was just invisible for broken markdown. I found out by checking the edit view. Please consider deleting your comment, it now is very confusing.

Answer (score 1):

I added a button and then had everything between the opening angular brace and forward slash deleted, then i simply typed NumberPicker (yes it was suggested) and vola! It appeared.